# New column in DataFrame based on rows and columns from another DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two pandas DataFrames.

```
df1

    col1    col2
0   E8      K4
1   E6      K3
2   E8      K4
3   E8      K4
4   E8      K2

df2

    group   K1  K2  K3  K4
0   E6      -2  -90 24  -23
1   E7      94  -34 3   22
2   E8      7   30  100 -9
```

In `df2`, for `E8 K4`, the value is

```
df2.loc[df2['group'] == 'E8']['K4'].item()
-9
```

But, how could I create a new column in `df1` based on `df2`?

The result will look like this:

```
    col1    col2    col3
0   E8      K4      -9
1   E6      K3      24
2   E8      K4      -9
3   E8      K4      -9
4   E8      K2      30
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) with reshaped values by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) for `MultiIndex Series`:

```
df = df1.join(df2.set_index('group').stack().rename('col3'), on=['col1','col2'])
print (df)
  col1 col2  col3
0   E8   K4    -9
1   E6   K3    24
2   E8   K4    -9
3   E8   K4    -9
4   E8   K2    30
```

Another idea with [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html), [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) and rename:

```
df = df1.merge(df2.melt('group', var_name='col2', value_name='col3')
                  .rename(columns={'group':'col1'}), on= ['col1','col2'], how='left')
      
print (df)
  col1 col2  col3
0   E8   K4    -9
1   E6   K3    24
2   E8   K4    -9
3   E8   K4    -9
4   E8   K2    30
```

Answer (score 0):

As [Pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) suggests, you can use `melt` function for `df2` to get your desired output easily:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'group': {0: 'E6', 1: 'E7', 2: 'E8'},
               'K1': {0: -2, 1: 94, 2: 7},
               'K2': {0: -90, 1: -34, 2: 30},
               'K3': {0: 24, 1: 3, 2: 100},
               'K4': {0: -23, 1: 22, 2: -9}})

pd.melt(df2, id_vars=['group'], value_vars=['K1', 'K2', 'K3', 'K4'])
```

returns:

```
group variable  value
0     E6       K1     -2
1     E7       K1     94
2     E8       K1      7
3     E6       K2    -90
4     E7       K2    -34
5     E8       K2     30
6     E6       K3     24
7     E7       K3      3
8     E8       K3    100
9     E6       K4    -23
10    E7       K4     22
11    E8       K4     -9
```